# How to cast a variable to a dataclass type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to use the function `fields` from the `dataclasses` module but my IDE keeps warning me that it should be only used on dataclasses (classes or instances). I know it is possible to ignore the warning, but I would like to cast my variable into a dataclass type, as it is more readable and IDE-compatible.

A brief example:

```
from dataclasses import fields

all_fields = fields(some_instance) # Here I get a warning
```

Context:

I want to write a "mixin" class to add type-enforcing on my dataclasses. Example:

```
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import fields, Field     

class TypedDCMixin:
    def __post_init__(self):
        self._check_fields_types()

    def _check_fields_types(self):
        for field in fields(self): # HERE I get the warning from my IDE 
            field_value = getattr(self, field.name)
            self._check_field_type(field, field_value)

    def _check_field_type(self, field: Field, field_value: Any):
        # whatever
        pass
```

The same warning would arise from any other context where `dataclasses.fields` is used with an argument which is not known to be a dataclass.

I usually avoid type warnings like that by using the function `typing.cast`, but there is no `DataclassType` for me to do `cast(DataclassType, self)` at the warned line.

Hence my question: How to cast a variable to a dataclass type?

Comment: I don't see any class in your code. Have a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/

Comment: The variable `some_instance` comes from somewhere else. We can suppose that it is a dataclass instance.

Comment: I'll second the request from Klaus. A simple import like this has no reason to trigger a warning. It probably lies in the definition of your dataclasses or fields function. Try to create another module with the same structure but dummy content to reproduce the issue with something you can post here.
It might also be related to the use of the name "fields" but I doubt it.

Comment: I've added some more context. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cast with the `dataclass` decorator works.

Modifying the original example to add the casting:

```
from typing import Any, cast
from dataclasses import fields, Field, dataclass   

class TypedDCMixin:
    def __post_init__(self):
        self._check_fields_types()

    def _check_fields_types(self):
        for field in fields(cast(dataclass, self)): # Here the casting is used  
            field_value = getattr(self, field.name)
            self._check_field_type(field, field_value)

    def _check_field_type(self, field: Field, field_value: Any):
        # whatever
        pass
```